# Dockerfile or Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I'm using Docker to containerize some applications. The structure of my projects (it's in a Github repo) is as follows:

```
app1/
|___ requirements.txt
|___ .env
|___ .gitignore
|___ .dockerignore
|___ app1.py
|___ Dockerfile
|___ download/
app2/
|___ requirements.txt
|___ .env
|___ .gitignore
|___ .dockerignore
|___ app2.py
|___ Dockerfile
|___ download/
```

These are independent projects that will save files in the respective *download/* directories. These files will be read by another app (actually a dashboard written in Dash) in a second stage.

What I want to know is how I should manage the dockerization of these 2 apps - I'm pretty new to Docker.

1. Do I need a docker-compose file? Maybe two? Maybe not at all? Are the Dockerfiles sufficient on their own?
2. How can I use the .env files in the dockerization process? They store all my env variables (connection to some databases and passwords) and I access them in my Python scripts through `os.gentenv('NAME_OF_THE_VARIABLE_AS_SAVED_IN_ENV_FILE)`. How to use them if I do not include a docker-compose.yml?
3. My Dockerfile do not list the ENV variables (they just call python:3.9-slim image, create a */app1* or */app2* directory and install the required packages listed in requirements.txt). Do they have to list all the env variables? How? Using ARG or ENV? And if I used a docker-compose approach, can I just reference the .env file?

I tested locally my 2 apps independently and they both work (but I had used default values for my env variabiles in my python scripts, something like `os.getenv(FOO, 'fake_value')`). I don't know how to put all this in production.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a docker-compose file? Maybe two? Maybe not at all? Are the Dockerfiles sufficient on their own?

You certainly don't *have* to use docker-compose to run two unrelated containers. You might want to read https://docs.docker.com/compose/features-uses/ , but I would get up and running basic docker containers first.

> How can I use the .env files in the dockerization process?

You can specify it when creating (running) a container:

```
docker run --env-file=.env.production ...
```

> Dockerfile ... ARG or ENV?

Dockerfile contains instructions for building an image. You then deploy the image and run a container based on it.

Unless you want the variables to be baked into the image (and I wouldn't want that for credentials), you don't need to reference them in a Dockerfile.